# Create a list of non blank cell values from a range?

Tags: arrays, excel

I have a spreadsheet like so:

```
Column A

Ducks
Frogs
<Blank>
Rabbits
<blank>
Horse
```

I want to be able to create a list of all non blank cells in a range (column A) like so:

```
Ducks
Frogs
Rabbits
Horse
```

I do not want blank values to be in my list.

Also, where there is a blank value found in the range, my formula should skip and list the next non blank cell in the range.

However at the moment i am getting 0

Here's my array formula, please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($F$16:$F$5000,IF($G$16:$G$5000<>"",ROW($1:$5000)),1),"")
```

Comment: Additionally, you could just delete blanks using `Go To Special...`. But if you want a formula....

Answer (score 2):

`IFERROR` in this set-up can be very inefficient, particularly if the size of the dataset being queried is large; cf my reply here:

https://superuser.com/questions/812727/look-up-a-value-in-a-list-and-return-all-multiple-corresponding-values

Better to use a single cell in which to record the number of expected number of returns, and reference that cell in an initial `IF` clause within the main formulas. For example, if we use cell `H16` for that purpose, we would put, in that cell:

`=COUNTIF(G$16:G$5000,"<>")`

The main array formula** is then:

`=IF(ROWS($1:1)>H$16,"",INDEX(F:F,SMALL(IF(G$16:G$5000<>"",ROW(G$16:G$5000)),ROWS($1:1))))`

and copied down until you get blanks.

For a unique list, change the formula in `H16` to:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(G16:G5000<>"",MATCH(F16:F5000,F16:F5000‌​,0)),ROW(F16:F5000)-MIN(ROW(F16:F5000))+1),1))`

and the main formula to:

`IF(ROWS($1:1)>H$16,"",INDEX(F:F,SMALL(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(G$16:G$5000<>"",MATCH(F$16:F$5000,F$16:F$5000,0)),ROW(F$16:F$5000)-MIN(ROW(F$16:F$5000))+1),ROW(F$16:F$5000)),ROWS($1:1))))`

Regards

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, this works really well. However is there a way to only list distinct values?

Comment: Did I miss that in your original question? Or do you need to amend it to reflect as such?

Comment: No you were spot on and understood the question completely, i was just wondering if there was a way the formula could be amended to discount duplicate values also? As in only show unique values? Thanks

Comment: You would change the formula in H16 to the following array formula**: =SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(G16:G5000<>"",MATCH(F16:F5000,F16:F5000,0)),ROW(F16:F5000)-MIN(ROW(F16:F5000))+1),1)) and the main array formula** would then be: =IF(ROWS($1:1)>H$16,"",INDEX(F:F,SMALL(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(G$16:G$5000<>"",MATCH(F$16:F$5000,F$16:F$5000,0)),ROW(F$16:F$5000)-MIN(ROW(F$16:F$5000))+1),ROW(F$16:F$5000)),ROWS($1:1))))

Comment: thanks for this code, however, excel says theres a problem with the first formula which would go in cell H16. Any ideas why?

Comment: Appears to be a problem with posting the formula within the comments. Have added to the post body.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you consider using `macro` for this issue (its in the toolbar options). you can record an empty macro and paste the code i have appended.
do note that macros overrides the ability to change back using history (ctrl+z). in the code the column is 16 and the last row is 5000, but you can change it.

```
Dim max As Integer
Dim colNum As Integer
Dim limit As Integer

max = 5000
colNum = 16

limit = max

For i = 1 To max
    If Cells(i, colNum) = "" Then
        Cells(i, colNum).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        If limit > 0 Then
            i = i - 1
            limit = limit - 1
        end if
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Surely there's a big danger of this going into an endless loop if I keeps being decreased by one?

Comment: It would be easier to decrement your loop by using `For i = max to 1 Step -1`.

Answer (score 0):

I find the other solutions (and most search engine hits for this topic) kind of illegible :) Adapting to another/more-general usage is hard if it is not clear of itself.

No idea about performance but this implements a list-of-non-blanks from column A:

`=INDEX( $A:$A, 2*ROW($A1)-COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,"<>") )`

It works by counting how many blank cells are *above* and using that as the running offset needed to "look ahead".